# App_Browsers .browser file for Firefox 4 supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=True

Tags: .net-4.0, firefox4

Unfortuantly, MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback stopped working in Firefox 4.  This breaks our websites and needs to be fixed.

I've added the following to our App_Browsers folder in our .NET 4/IIS7 website:

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="Firefox4" parentID="Firefox">
      <identification>
          <capability name="majorversion" match="4" />
      </identification>

      <capabilities>
          <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      </capabilities>
  </browser>  
</browsers>
```

Yet, support for MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback remains false for Firefox 4.  I've also have tried changing several other properties and none of them are affecting the defaults for firefox.  Please help.